# Ternary operator in Template Literal HTML TABLE

Tags: javascript, css, ternary-operator, template-literals

I am trying to set my table data to have a background color of red if it has a "Failed" status.  I am having a hard time setting this inline style.  At first I tried to use the ternary operator in the second td of the createTableData function but could not get it to work.  Right now I am attempting to break it out into its own  function but not working either.

Looking for help on setting the background color of my table data.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3">
            Active Directory Replication Health
        </h1>
    </div>



<div id="table"></div>


</div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Script

```
var data = [

{
    "DC":  "SV07CTDC1",
    "Connectivity":  "Passed",
    "Advertising":  "Failed"
},
{
    "DC":  "SVGCCTDC1",
    "Connectivity":  "Passed",
    "Advertising":  "Failed"
}
];

function checkStatus(status) {
status === "Failed" ? "background-color: red" : "background-color: blue"
}


function createTableData(dc ){
var html = ''
for( key in dc )
    html += `   
        <tr>
            <td> ${key} </td>
            <td style=${checkStatus(dc[key])} > ${dc[key]} </td>
        </tr>

`
return html
}


function createTable(dc) {
return `
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6  ">
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                ${createTableData(dc)}



        </table>
    </div>  
`
}






document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = `
<div class="row">
    ${data.map(createTable).join("")}
</div>
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're missing in your **checkStatus** method is to return the condition result;

```
function checkStatus(status) {
  return status === "Failed" ? "background-color: red" : "background-color: blue"
}
```

updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvXQLo)

Comment: Whilst this works, its certainly convoluted. It could easily be cleaned up

Comment: @Jasonbamber Can you give me ideas on clean up?